# Undefined variable Trying to fix my contact form

Tags: php, email, contact-form

I have been trying to fix my contact form wherein the data can be sent via email. But i seem to have some errors at the start. It says in the web page "Undefined variable" yet. I'm only following a tutorial that i have been reading and i'm not yet adept in PHP. I'm using XAMPP at the moment in order to run my PHP

**Here is the HTML Markup**

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Contact Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<h1>Contact Form</h1>
<p class="error"> There are some misisng fields.</p>
<?php if($error == true) { ?>
<?php } if($sent == true) { ?>
<p class="sent">Thank you for sending your message</p><?php } ?>

<div class="contactform">
<form name="contact"  action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">

<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" />
<label for="email">Email:</label>
<input type="email" name="email" />
<label for="comments">Comments:</label>
<textarea name="comments"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="submit" /> 
</form>
</div>
```

**Here is the PHP Code**

```
<?php if($_POST['submit']) {
if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['comments'])) {
    $error = true;
} else {

     $to = "clestcruz@gmail.com";

     $name = trim($_POST['name']);
     $email = trim($_POST['email']);
     $comments = trim($_POST['comments']);

     $subject = "Contact Form";

     $messages = "Name: $name \r\n Email: $email \r\n Comments: $comments";
     $headers = "From:" . $name;
     $mailsent = mail($to, $subject, $messages, $headers);

     if($mailsent){
         $sent= true;
    }
}
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

**Undefine Variables**

```
<?php if($error == true) { ?>

<?php } if($sent == true) { ?>

if($_POST['submit']) {
```

Comment: Are the `$_POST` values the unidentified variables?

Comment: Hello Jm please see my edited post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try declaring the variables before you use it. PHP will give out a notice if you don't pass a value first.

```
<?php 
$error=false;
$sent=false;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['comments'])) {
    $error = true;
} else {

     $to = "clestcruz@gmail.com";

     $name = trim($_POST['name']);
     $email = trim($_POST['email']);
     $comments = trim($_POST['comments']);

     $subject = "Contact Form";

     $messages = "Name: $name \r\n Email: $email \r\n Comments: $comments";
     $headers = "From:" . $name;
     $mailsent = mail($to, $subject, $messages, $headers);

     if($mailsent){
         $sent= true;
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, i guess the tutorial i was reading wasn't complete. Now i just need to figure out on how to pass the data via email

Comment: NVM. I already got it working. I just uploaded into a free hosting server :D

Comment: It's just a notice because undeclared variables may give you garbage values. But the best coding practice is you declare it before you use it. The free hosting server must have disabled the error reporting for these kind of notices. Good luck on your PHP journeys! Cheers :D

Comment: thanks man. I'm actually working on a wordpress theme atm and i need to learn on how to send the data via email because the theme has a "Contact Us" page .

Answer (score 0):

These lines:

```
<?php if($error == true) { ?>
<?php } if($sent == true) { ?>
```

appear near the top of your HTML, but as far as I can see, there's been no PHP executed at this point, so `$error` and `$sent` won't be defined.

This line:

```
if($_POST['submit']) {
```

is testing for a value, but unless your form has been submitted, it too won't be defined. You could test this more effectively with

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   // do stuff
 }
```

Comment: You'll need some code at the top to determine what to do. Basically you need to split it down into two sections: if (the form has been submitted) {send the mail} else {display the form}.

Comment: I have tried replacing the line of code with the one you suggested it seems my form disappeared or cannot be displayed. I'm still new to PHP so i'll need to do a lot of trial and error